# Writing context with dynamic values in reactive streams

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I want to set some values in context but I could not find any way to get this from the data inside the flux.
There is a Logging filter which picks up these values from the reactive context and sets the values in MDC context, the filter is verified to work if I pass a static value to writeContext but that does not solve the problem for me.

Could someone please take a look and suggest how could it be set.

```
Flux.just(Map.of("k1", "v1"), Map.of("k2", "v2"))
        .contextWrite(Context.of("key", "something"));
```

In the code block above I would like to set values like `k1, k2` in place of `"something"`.

Comment: you should be able to use flatMap and then in the flatMap get the context by calling `Mono. deferContextual` but i have never done this, because placing things in the context, especially a lot of data will impact performance. Here is examples https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_simple_context_examples

Comment: well you could use a `map` to mutate values when you need them